# Navigation and tab bar missing when presenting view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I am implementing home screen shortcuts using 3D Touch, and it's working well, however the way I currently have it means that when the shortcut takes the user to a specific view controller, the tab bar and navigation bar is missing.

This is my code:

```
func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    var handled = false

    if let shortcutType = ShortcutType.init(rawValue: shortcutItem.type) {
        let rootViewController = window!.rootViewController

        switch shortcutType {
        case .Favourites:
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("favourites") as! FavouritesTableViewController
            rootController.parkPassed = DataManager.sharedInstance.getParkByName(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("currentPark")!)
            self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            handled = true
        }
    return handled
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I need to change in the code?

This is the starboard layout (FavouritesTableViewController is indicated):

[image]

EDIT:

Here is my updated code:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    var handled = false

    if let shortcutType = ShortcutType.init(rawValue: shortcutItem.type) {
        switch shortcutType {
        case .Favourites:
            print("favourites")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("favourites") as! FavouritesViewController
            rootController.parkPassed = DataManager.sharedInstance.getParkByName(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("currentPark")!)

            let root = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            if let navCont = root.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController {
                navCont.presentViewController(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                root.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            root.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            handled = true
        }
    }
    return handled
}
```

Comment: if they are missing, then you are presenting it from the window root view which is what you're doin now. YOu have to make your tabb bar as rootview, and then present within your tabbar

Comment: How would I do that? I've updated my question with the storyboard layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Get the delegate from app delegate:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

GEt the controller you would like to to present from storyboard:

```
Controller *cont=//get the reference from storyboard either using storyboard ID
```

and then make your rootview present the other controller:

```
[appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:cont animated:YES completion:^{
                            DLog(@"presented your view ON TOP of the  tab bar controller");
                        }];
```

**Swift:**

```
  var appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate()
  var cont: Controller = //get the reference form storyboard
  appDelegate.window.rootViewController.presentViewController(cont, animated: true, completion: {    DLog("presented your view ON TOP of the  tab bar controller")

 })
```

you can move the presenting stuff on main thread,if  you like!!!!

Comment: Once again, please note that your tabbar must be the root view controller

Comment: This still results in presentation without the tabor for me.... Any idea why?  My view hierarchy is as follows: Root: Tabbar Controller -> Nav controller -> destinationView.

Answer (score 2):

So I got the solution I hope that will work for you.

First you have to set your Storyboard instance.

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

after that you need to set where you want to start the navigation.

```
let mynVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("root") as! UINavigationController
```

right now you can set the viewcontroller that you want to appear

```
let playVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("playVC")
```

So and now you can start the workflow but note that you have to do this in a completion like this

```
 self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(rootVC, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            rootVC.pushViewController(playVC, animated: true)
        })
```

So your rootViewController will present you "rootVC" and after that your playVC.

I hope It will help you guys:)

Comment: This still results in presentation without the tabor for me.... Any idea why? My view hierarchy is as follows: Root: Tabbar Controller -> Nav controller -> destinationView.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are setting the view controller(named:`rootController`) to be the `window?.rootViewController`, other than presenting the `rootController` by the `window?.rootViewController`. Just change

```
self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
```

to

```
self.window?.rootViewController.presentViewController(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However it's giving me this: `Warning: Attempt to present <Alton_Towers_Times.FavouritesViewController: 0x14ff1b060> on <UINavigationController: 0x1500db800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Answer (score 0):

if you use it like this you will be replaced rootview to this viewcontroller. So this will be a new solo page and its normal to dont have navigationController or tabbarController. Because you have only this new page in view hierarchy. 
If you want to present this from rootview, you may try

```
 let root=UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    if let navCont=root.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController
    {
        navCont.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        root.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: oh! use    root.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() too. i used this one of my old projects. It was working

Comment: It's still giving me the warning. I've posted my updated code so you can check it out.